# R Shiny 1.6 with {bslib} Package: Navbar Styling on Mobile - Bootstrap 4 vs. Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, r, bootstrap-4, shiny

I recently updated to Shiny version 1.6 to use the newly incorporated `bslib` package's Bootstrap 4 styling. However, I am having trouble styling a `navbarPage` for mobile when moving from version 3 to version 4 (using the `bslib::theme()` method within a `navbarPage`.

Here is a sample app for styling with Bootsrap 3:

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) { 
  
  bootstrapPage(
    navbarPage(
      id = "dir",
      theme = bs_theme(
        version = 3,
        bootswatch = "yeti"
        ),
      title = "Mobile Testing", 
      windowTitle = "Mobile Testing", 
      collapsible = TRUE,
      
      ## First navbarMenu
      navbarMenu(
        title = "Menu #1", 
        tabPanel(title = "Tab 1", "Tab 1"), 
        tabPanel(title = "Tab 2", "Tab 2"), 
        tabPanel(title = "Tab 3", "Tab 3")
        ), 
      ## Second navbarMenu
      navbarMenu(
        title = "Menu #2", 
        tabPanel(title = "Tab 1", "Tab 1"), 
        tabPanel(title = "Tab 2", "Tab 2"), 
        tabPanel(title = "Tab 3", "Tab 3")
        ), 
      tabPanel(title = "Tab #1")
      )
    )
  
  }

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  ## empty server
  })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is what the mobile layout for this looks like (the title or navbar-brand is stuck to the left-hand side, and the hamburger button is stuck to the right-hand side):

[image: bslib::theme(version = 3)]

Now, if you update the `theme = bs_theme()` function with `version = 4` instead of `version = 3` you get the following mobile layout (hamburger button stuck to the left-hand side and the title/navbar-brand stuck next to the hamburger button):

[image: bslib::theme(version = 4)]

I have tried to use CSS to change the way this is oriented, but I can't seem to figure out how to override the default CSS that Shiny is using. I have also tried to modify the HTML to see if I can get these to flip around and look like the `version = 3` styling (which appears to be the default Bootstrap 4 styling from what I can tell per https://bootswatch.com/yeti/), but I haven't had any luck. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can achieve the orientation of the `version = 3` setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up, I opened an issue with the package maintainer [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/issues/289) - this does appear to be a bug. Anyway, after looking at the commit that was made, I was able to add the following CSS to my stylesheet to fix this issue:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {  
  .navbar-header {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      float: right !important;
  }
}
```

I assume this will be fixed with a future update to the `bslib` package.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug. Raise issue in package repository in github. You can override default css with !important

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I submitted a github issue on the package repo page. I'll see if it is addressed.